# check_nrpe -c CheckProcState USING PID

Tags: centos, nagios, task-manager, nsclient++

I'm currently running a SOLR search engine from a batch file and it appears as a process in my servers taskmgr. I need to monitor its state using `check_nrpe` but since there are more than one cmd.exe processes, I need to identify it using the PID of that process.

Can anyone provide me with an example syntax of how to do that? My syntax:

```
./check_nrpe -H IP -p port -c CheckProcState -a MinWarnCount=1 MinCritCount=0 cmd.exe (-ppid=2664)
```

The `--ppid=2664` was just a lousy attempt to get it right but no results...

Comment: Why don't you use an actual Nagios plugin for solr? You'll get much better results. And it will actually work. Github has several to choose from...

Comment: I'm using Icinga (with NSClient++) since I have lots of other things to monitor. So it really needs to be monitored this way :s

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Icinga is perfectly capable of using Nagios plugins.

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you meant... Duhh... Thank you very much! But still, it would be very nice to know if it's possible to use CheckProcState using only PID. If I have other processes to monitor..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an actual Nagios plugin for solr? You'll get much better results. And it will actually work. Icinga is perfectly capable of using Nagios plugins. Github has several to choose from...

Answer (score 0):

NSClient++ 0.4.2 introduces support for checking/filtering pids (along with a lot of other options).

```
check_process process=cmd.exe "filter=pid = 1234" "crit=count = 0"
```